# action bar background hides the title android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

after i changed my action bar's color the title disappeared
all i see is an action bar with an orange background with no text. if i remove the "actionBarStyle" attribute the text appear.
all i want to do is to have white color for my title's text and up button.
my style.xml:

```
<style name="SprayTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/orange_background</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/background_material_light</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
    parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_blue_grey_800</item>

    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is very fundamental solution:
change your parent style to

```
<style name="SprayTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

and no need to give extra text style if you want only white text color.

Comment: thats what i did and it worked! thanks but what if i want red color for text?

Comment: You can include text style, but do it properly like [Given here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use spans to have white title:

```
SpannableString title = new SpannableString("ExampleTitle");
title.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(android.R.color.white), 0, title.getLength());
```

and then:

```
getActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

Comment: i tried that but it only changes the title but NOT the menu items and the back button.

Comment: @user4135569 Question asks only about the title.

Comment: i meant all the items on action bar. sorry.